# How to write HTML page code for various device types?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a three-column website that is coded as a single column (responsive) up to 767 px. I want to set a 3 column view beginning for devices from (including) 768px.

I already have this working partially, but I need a smaller font size for devices beginning from 768 px.

Currently I have the following HTML code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) { 
.wrap { 
display: block; 
} 
.tc { 
display: block; 
width: auto; 
border: none; 
}
```

And other HTML code within this code.

The above makes a single column display for devices up to 767px.

I want to know what to write for viewport sizes above 767px which then starts with the Apple iPad, which is 768px default portrait size, and then higher px? I already have following code for max-width declared to up to 1240px.

What is the HTML/CSS code for devices 768px and above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a media query with `min-width` instead like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) { 
    // your css here
}
```

Comment: That would be after the 767 media query code right?

Comment: Yes. The styles within that media query is applied when the width is 768px or more.

Comment: Yes, one media query that targets 767px and below and another media query that targets 768px and above.

Comment: @sd100 Glad I could help. Cheers.